# How do we deal with "how do you say..." questions?

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Here's an example. [How do I say 'It feels like' in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4581/how-do-i-say-it-feels-like-in-spanish)

The question is fairly elementary, or basic. That's not what bothers me, because I'm only an "advanced beginner" myself.

The issue in questions by this one individual, is that he does not even attempt a Spanish translation in his questions. Given this fact, I'm not even sure that he understands Spanish.

I have written in comments that such questions should contain a translation attempt. If it's wrong, fine; we're here to fix it. That's different from having to provide a translation "from scratch."

Most SE programming or Stack Overflow questions are expected to contain a piece of relevant code, and likewise, most language sites expect people to use the language and demonstrate that they have least of modicum of knowledge in it.

Is this the standard we should use on Spanish SE?

Comment: +1 Wonderful. This is what I was after!

Answer (score 5):

Not a complete answer, but rather the reason I found reasonable to downvote that question was JoulSauron's comment on chat "La Tertulia" on the closure of other question:

> It is off-topic for a number of reasons, mainly because the site is not for translations and because I can't see any future visitor seeking for such list, so it would be too localized (... *and it then goes on explaining punctual reasons on about other question.*)

So, I suggests to accept only translation requests that already contain attempts by humans (no automatic or online translators).  Some rules of the sister sites stackexchange, math.SE, physics.SE, TeX.SE, German.SE, Russian.SE –the only ones I'm familiar with- are like that. I think it's a necessary (perhaps not sufficient) criterion to allow only questions with attempts. It works for other sites.